# R server requests for json

Tags: json, r

I haven't been able to find an example yet but is there a way to use R to send requests to a server?  I know of packages that will allow you to convert data to and from JSON files.  Essentially I want to request certain data from a server I have set up, that server will then compile a JSON file depending on what I have requested and then R will download the JSON file and then convert it into an R friendly format.  I know how to download a JSON file from the server its just the request part that is the issue.  Can anyone give an example?

Thanks;

For more info:  I'm building a Shiny web app in R.  I also have the packages rjson and RJSONIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a package like [httpRequest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httpRequest/index.html) to send/receive request from server, including JSON payload.
This package has documentation in the form of a PDF.

PS: there may be newer packages available, but this one works for me. Feel free to look for one that'd fit your needs.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly the package I was looking for.